# How to handle space in YUI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, yui

I am using [YUI 2 autocomplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_basic_xhr.html), I have my own web service which provides suggestions.
Whenever user enters " " (space) then suggestions were not displayed. Like if user enters "`foo bar`" then suggestion are displayed till "`foo`" but once user enters " " then suggestion are not displayed.
I checked the Ajax calls and observed that space is replaced by "`%20`". So after space each Ajax call contains "`%20`" and that's why no records are retrieved from database.
I tried setting space as delimiter.If we use space as delimiter then it will show suggestions for new term (which user typed after space). Like if you enter "`foo bar`" then after space it will show suggestion for "`bar`" while I want suggestions for complete "`foo bar`" term.
I want to display suggestion for complete term whatever user had typed including space.
Is there any way to handle this in YUI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoded URL by overriding `generateRequest` method and it worked :)

```
myAutoComp.generateRequest = function(sQuery) {
    return "myProject/index.php?query=" + encodeURIComponent(sQuery);
};
```

Comment: @zladuric: You gave me a chance to answer myself :)

Answer (score 0):

```
YUI().use('autocomplete', 'autocomplete-highlighters', function (Y) {
   Y.one('#ac-input').plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
      resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
      source: 'your url'
    });
});
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: Can you please add something to your answer ? As I am not sure how it deals with space ?

Comment: @zladuric: I think My_Boon talking about YUI3. I am trying YUI2.

Comment: Yes, you stated so in the question. Which is why I started writing the answer when you beat me to it :)